# I don't understand why these bikes have the specific frame sizes

Tags: frames, size

Why does huffy's Rock Creek mountain bike have the same size frame for the 26-in and the 24-in but the 29-in version has a huge frame like a 26-in mountain bike should not have the same size frame as a 24 in nore should it be the same size frames as the 29 in there should be three different frame sizes

---

Huffy 26" Rock Creek MTB, from https://www.walmart.com/ip/Huffy-26-inch-Rock-Creek-Men-s-Mountain-Bike-Blue/1121295

[image]

---

Huffy 29" Rock Creek MTB, from https://www.walmart.com/ip/Huffy-29-Rock-Creek-Men-s-Mountain-Bike-Black/884827594

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site - your question is kinda hard to follow.  I've found two of the bikes you've mentioned, and included stock photos.  Could you please tell us a bit more what you're asking?  Is it why the small/med/large frame sizes aren't directly comparable between models ?

Comment: Bikes with different wheel sizes can have the same frame size. Not with the rim brakes in your bikes but with disc brakes you can often use the same bike with wheels of different diameter and change the wheels as you like. There is no problem with that in general, although specific bikes can have various limits for that.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I wonder if the question is more "how can walmart sell a bigger and a smaller bike for the same price?"   We need OP to clarify the question some.

Comment: Yes, maybe JØKËR just does not like that they sell two bikes with the same frame. Anyway, these are very cheap bikes if not outright BSO's. It is not worth spending too much thought about their design. BTW, the big-big gear in the top photo looks very ugly. The mid-top gear in the bottom photo looks at least usable. Better brands would probably choose big-small.

Comment: The 29” version has clearly longer rear triangle and more BB drop so I wouldn’t call it the same frame

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the money.

On the one hand a bike maker would like to have different size bikes for all sizes of people so that they have a bike in each size slot, increasing sales.

Going from two different frame sizes to only one reduces inventory cost and manufacturing cost.

Having one frame size with two different size wheels is cheaper than having two different frames.

The 29er wheel size or desired specifications were enough different to drive the maker to have a different frame for that wheel.